# Decorators on functions

Tags: javascript, babeljs, decorator, ecmascript-next, javascript-decorators

I see that babel.js decorators (available in "stage 1") implement the spec at https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators. It appears that decorators are limited to (1) classes, (2) accessors, and (3) methods. In my case, I want to use decorators on plain old **functions**, as in

```
@chainable
function foo() { }
```

where (just an example)

```
function chainable(fn) {
  return function() {
    fn.apply(this, arguments);
    return this;
  };
}
```

I don't see any logical reason why decorators should not be able to apply to functions. My question is, is there some way to accomplish this? Or is there some good reason why functions cannot be decorated?

It turns out there is an issue raised for this at https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators/issues/4.

Answer (score 38):

To execute a decorator, you evaluate an expression and doing that prevents hoisting (even for a variable declaration, the right-hand side of an assignment stays put). Therefore, it is not compatible with function declarations being hoisted.

As a work-around, I suggested that function expressions, generator function expressions and arrow functions could be enabled to be decorated:

```
const func = @someDecorator('abc') (x, y) => { return x + y };
```

Alas, that wasn’t met with much enthusiasm: [Decorators for functions](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/decorators-for-functions)

Comment: Instead of `const func = @someDecorator('abc') (x, y) => { return x + y };`, why wouldn't you just write `const func = someDecorator('abc')((x, y) => { return x + y });`? IMO that tiny extra bit of syntax doesn't really get you anything in that instance.

Comment: +1 for your first suggestion on the thread about preventing hoisting when a function is decorated, fwiw :)

Comment: @Ajedi32: when there's multiple decorators, it reads much better.  Consider `decorator1('abc')(decorator2('def')(decorator3('ghi')((x, y) => ...)))` vs `@decorator1('abc') @decorator2('def') @decorator3('ghi') (x, y) => ...`.  Typing that first part out actually took me longer than it should to make sure the closing parens were correct.

Comment: Oh wow. If Dr. Rauschmayer answered my question on SO I'd be star struck. :D

Answer (score 8):

You certainly have a point here.

But as [**neo_blackcap** pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31772083/1202461), function decorator are not part of the [ES7 decorators draft](https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators).

So, the best thing you can do is to [start discussion on the corresponding tracker](https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators/issues) to attract community attention to your proposal.

ES7 decorators are on their <s>[first stage of development](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/)</s> [second stage of development](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators), meaning that their API is still under development and could undergo any change.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is function decorator has not been ES7 draft.

Of course, you still can implement your function decorator by yourself

Comment: By implementing it myself, you mean writing my own parser/transpiler?

Comment: @torazaburo no, you can write a babel plugin

Comment: https://github.com/ukari/javascript-let-decorators Someone has done it, a lot of people keep asking for this feature but there seems no proper babel plugin