# Do any babel plugin support JS decorators on functions?

Tags: javascript, function, decorator, babeljs

I'm aware that the ES7 draft doesn't support decorators for functions ([question 31771856](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31771856/decorators-on-functions)), only for classes and methods. I find that unfortunate as they are awfully convenient. Is there any existing babel plugin that implements this functionality? I'm searched the web but haven't found any, which I find surprising.