# Typescript 5.0 decorators inside React functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-decorator

I'd like to use typescript 5.0 new decorators inside a react functional component
to add functions the ability to update state.

However I get two compilation error:

1. at myDecorator definition -> Cannot find name 'DecoratorContext'
2. at myDecorator usage      -> Decorators are not valid here.

I updated to typescript@latest (getting warning from react-script requesting previous version but hope would work anyway).

Any suggestion? Can I use decorator there?

Here is what I tried

```
export function MyComponent() {
    const [myState, setMyState] = useState(0);
    const myRef = useRef(new MyClass());
    function myDecorator(originalMethod: any, context: DecoratorContext) {
        
        return function() {
            setMyState(myRef.current.state);
            originalMethod();
        };
    }

    @myDecorator
    function myFunctionToBeDecorated(){
        console.log("Hello World");
    };

}
```

Comment: Decorators can only decorate class methods, not plain functions. FWIW I hate that limitation, but it is a thing.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/33916017/1915893